# Choose landing page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app, which can be started in one of two modes.  Depending on the mode, which is triggered from the query string, I'd like to go to a different page.  What's the best way to achieve this please?

(I'm still using Router v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to the bottom of my index.js page, and it allows me to select a different index / landing page depending on my custom logic.

```
if(history.getCurrentLocation().pathname === "/") {
    // no path has been specified, so this is an index query. Decide the most suitable index page

    if(customLogicHere) {
      history.push('/firstOption');
    } else {
      history.push('/secondOption');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, what are you planning to do with other pages, do you want to keep your mode in path like this `mode/my-page` or simply you want to welcome your user differently depends on mode with `/?mode=new-user`. If the second option is your model, I would simply displya other component in you container with render method

```
render() {
 const myview = mode === 0 ? <ViewOne /> : <ViewTwo />;
 return (myview);
}
```

hope I've helped

Comment: Thanks, yes that is helpful.  Although I've just stumbled upon another solution which I'll post up in case it helps others